# Windows phone 8 Change control's height to view height

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

There is a simple task in W8 and C# which for some reason can't accomplice. I want my WebBrowser height to be equal to my view height,programmatically.( I was able to performe this task with VS2008 with the dock property)
I have tried:

```
MainPage mainView = new MainPage();
webBrowser1.Height = mainView.WindowHeight;
```

My reason for doing this is because when i change my device to 720x1280,my view's height is enlarged but leaving my webbroswer control with the same height.
Any help or code suggestions would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just give it an undefined height in XAML, that way it fills the available space? I'm not sure what MainPage is, but if that's a PhoneApplicationPage, it won't work. You would have to  listen to an event like Loaded, and from there use `ActualHeight`

Comment: Are you using an MVVM framework on this?  Which one?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += delegate
        {
            webBrowser1.Height = this.ActualHeight;

            //if you want to add the web browser to main page,uncomment the next line.
            //this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(webBrowser1);
        };
    }
```

hope this can help you.